# Error en obtención de datos "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at"

Tags: java

he estado un poco atorado con este error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
```

He leído que el error es por un objeto vacío en el programa, pero no logro identificar cuál es, me dice las líneas de las clases que tienen eso pero no comprendo el porqué, si estoy utilizando mal algún concepto, espero puedan ayudarme

**Esa es la clase Principal donde llamo a los métodos para pedir la info**

```
package implementacion;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import clases.Archivo;
import clases.Usuario;

public class Principal {
ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
Usuario aux= new Usuario();
private ArrayList<Archivo> archivo= new ArrayList<Archivo>();
int opcion;

public Principal(){
    do{
        opcion = Integer.parseInt(
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        "0: Salir\n"
                        + "1: Agregar archivo\n"
                        + "2: Mostrar Información\n"                            
                    )
                );
        switch (opcion) {
        case 0:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Adios!");
            break;
        case 1:
            agregarArchivo();
            break;
        case 2:
            mostrarInformacion();
            break;

        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opcion inválida.");
            break;
        }
    }while(opcion !=0);

}

public void agregarArchivo(){
    Archivo auxiliarArchivo = new Archivo();
    auxiliarArchivo.solicitarInformacion();
    archivo.add(auxiliarArchivo);

}

public void mostrarInformacion(){
    String cadenaArchivo="";
    for(int i=0;i<archivo.size();i++){
        cadenaArchivo+=archivo.get(i).toString()+"\n";
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,cadenaArchivo);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Principal();
}
```

Y estas son las otras clases

**Clase archivo**

```
package clases;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Archivo {
private String nombreArchivo; //Incluye la extension
private int tamanioBytes;
private Usuario usuarioSubio; //Composición
private ArrayList <Usuario> usuariosCompartio = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
private String nombreCarpeta;
private Fecha fechaModificacion;
private Fecha fechaSubida;

public Archivo(){}

public Archivo(String nombreArchivo, int tamanioBytes, Usuario usuarioSubio, ArrayList<Usuario> usuarioscompartio,
        String nombreCarpeta, Fecha fechaModificacion, Fecha fechaSubida) {
    super();
    this.nombreArchivo = nombreArchivo;
    this.tamanioBytes = tamanioBytes;
    this.usuarioSubio = usuarioSubio;
    this.usuariosCompartio = usuarioscompartio;
    this.nombreCarpeta = nombreCarpeta;
    this.fechaModificacion = fechaModificacion;
    this.fechaSubida = fechaSubida;
}
public String getNombreArchivo() {
    return nombreArchivo;
}
public void setNombreArchivo(String nombreArchivo) {
    this.nombreArchivo = nombreArchivo;
}
public int getTamanioBytes() {
    return tamanioBytes;
}
public void setTamanioBytes(int tamanioBytes) {
    this.tamanioBytes = tamanioBytes;
}
public Usuario getUsuarioSubio() {
    return usuarioSubio;
}
public void setUsuarioSubio(Usuario usuarioSubio) {
    this.usuarioSubio = usuarioSubio;
}
public ArrayList<Usuario> getUsuariosCompartio() {
    return usuariosCompartio;
}
public void setUsuariosCompartio(ArrayList<Usuario> usuariosCompartio) {
    this.usuariosCompartio = usuariosCompartio;
}
public String getNombreCarpeta() {
    return nombreCarpeta;
}
public void setNombreCarpeta(String nombreCarpeta) {
    this.nombreCarpeta = nombreCarpeta;
}
public Fecha getFechaModificacion() {
    return fechaModificacion;
}
public void setFechaModificacion(Fecha fechaModificacion) {
    this.fechaModificacion = fechaModificacion;
}
public Fecha getFechaSubida() {
    return fechaSubida;
}
public void setFechaSubida(Fecha fechaSubida) {
    this.fechaSubida = fechaSubida;
}
public void solicitarInformacion(){
    verificarExtensionArchivo();
    this.usuarioSubio.solicitarInfo();
    this.nombreCarpeta = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre de la carpeta");
    this.fechaModificacion.solicitarInformacion();
    this.fechaSubida.solicitarInformacion();
    verificarTamanioArchivo();
    Usuario aux= new Usuario();
    for (int i=0; i<4 ;i++){
        aux.solicitarInfo();
        usuariosCompartio.add(aux);
    }

}
public void verificarTamanioArchivo(){
    do{
        this.tamanioBytes = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño en bytes"));
    }while (this.tamanioBytes>524288000);
}
public void verificarExtensionArchivo(){
    do{
        this.nombreArchivo= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del archivo");
    }while (this.nombreArchivo.contains(".exe") || this.nombreArchivo.contains(".bat"));
}
```

**Clase Usuario**

```
public class Usuario {
private String nombreUsuario;
private String correoElectronico;

public Usuario(String nombreUsuario, String correoElectronico) {
    this.nombreUsuario = nombreUsuario;
    this.correoElectronico = correoElectronico;
}

public Usuario(){}

public String getNombreUsuario() {
    return nombreUsuario;
}

public void setNombreUsuario(String nombreUsuario) {
    this.nombreUsuario = nombreUsuario;
}

public String getCorreoElectronico() {
    return correoElectronico;
}

public void setCorreoElectronico(String correoElectronico) {
    this.correoElectronico = correoElectronico;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Usuario [nombreUsuario=" + nombreUsuario + ", correoElectronico=" + correoElectronico + "]";
}

public void solicitarInfo(){
    this.nombreUsuario = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre de usuario");
    verificarCorreoElectronico();
}
public void verificarCorreoElectronico(){
    do{
        this.correoElectronico= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el correo electrónico");
    }while (this.correoElectronico.contains("@")!= true);
}
```

**Clase Fecha**

```
public class Fecha {
private int dia;
private int mes;
private int anio;
public Fecha(int dia, int mes, int anio) {
    this.dia = dia;
    this.mes = mes;
    this.anio = anio;
}

public Fecha(){}
public int getDia() {
    return dia;
}
public void setDia(int dia) {
    this.dia = dia;
}
public int getMes() {
    return mes;
}
public void setMes(int mes) {
    this.mes = mes;
}
public int getAnio() {
    return anio;
}
public void setAnio(int anio) {
    this.anio = anio;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Fecha [dia=" + dia + ", mes=" + mes + ", anio=" + anio + "]";
}


public void solicitarInformacion(){
    String fecha = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la fecha");
    String fechaPartida[] = fecha.split("--");  
    for (int i = 0 ; i<3; i++){
        switch(i){
        case 0:
            this.dia = Integer.parseInt(fechaPartida[i]);
            break;
        case 1:
            this.mes= Integer.parseInt(fechaPartida[i]);
            break;
        case 2:
            this.anio =mes= Integer.parseInt(fechaPartida[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
public void verificarFechaValida(){}
```

Comment: Muestra la parte del mensaje de error, alrededor de donde dice `Caused by...`así se podrá saber dónde está el error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 **at clases.Archivo.solicitarInformacion(Archivo.java:73)**
 **at implementacion.Principal.agregarArchivo(Principal.java:46)**
 **at implementacion.Principal.<init>(Principal.java:30)**
 **at implementacion.Principal.main(Principal.java:61)**

Ahí es donde me da error, no sé si podrán detectar las líneas, pero son esras

  **this.usuarioSubio.solicitarInfo(); (llínea 73)**
  **auxiliarArchivo.solicitarInformacion(); (línea 46)**
    **agregarArchivo(); (línea 30)**
  **new Principal(); (línea 46)**

Comment: ¿No aparece `Caused by`en tu mensaje de error?

Comment: No, sólo esto aparece
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at clases.Archivo.solicitarInformacion(Archivo.java:73)
 at implementacion.Principal.agregarArchivo(Principal.java:46)
 at implementacion.Principal.<init>(Principal.java:30)
 at implementacion.Principal.main(Principal.java:61)**

Comment: En este método `public void solicitarInformacion(){...` parece que re-envías al mismo método, por ejemplo: `this.fechaModificacion.solicitarInformacion();` Pero viendo tu código a primera vista, tiene varios errores de concepción y de lógica. No es para desanimarte, pero creo que es mejor que revises todo desde el principio, si no a la medida que tu programa crece se te irá haciendo menos entendible.

Comment: No, en la clase fecha hay un método que se llama public void solicitarFecha() **lo he cambiado para ver si era eso** que hace lo mismo, que es pedirle al usuario que ingrerese la fecha y luego partiirla en tókens, pero el problema no es ese, sigue marcando el mismo error y no es en esos métodos, sinceramente no sé por qué manda eso :/

Comment: El mensaje es claro. Hay un objeto con valor a null, en la clase `Archivo`, en el método `solicitarInformacion` en la línea 73. No puede ser más preciso que eso. Si quieres más ayuda, puedes comenzar por identificar cual es esa línea 73 (asumiendo que no has modificado el código desde que recibistes el error).

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema está clarísimo. Tu variable `usuarioSubio` es `null` porque no la inicializas en ningún momento. Por eso te salta esa excepción cuando llamas al método `solicitarInfo()` sobre un objeto que es `null`.

Para arreglarlo deberías inicializarla con el método `setUsuarioSubio(Usuario usuarioSubio)` o usando el otro contructor de `Archivo` que te pide un `Usuario` como argumento y en cualquiera de los dos casos pasarle un objeto `Usuario` instanciado.

Ese error se te repetirá si no lo corriges para el resto de campos a los que tampoco les asignas un valor y utilizas luego.